# DlinkDDNS configuration

Tags: ddns

I have a Dlink DIR-600 router. I have registered a dlinkddns account and set it on the router's configuration panel. It says all OK, but this subdomain is not working. It is pointed to my actual IP, but it does not show the welcome page on my localhost. Why? What should be the problem? Are there some essential settings in the router?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if:

- Going to `localhost` does not work or
- Going to your ddns address does not work while it does for `localhost`.

For the first case, if you intend to host webpages, you need to use something like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) which allows you to configure a quick and easy apache-based solution. You may check out other alternatives searching for "AMP (solution stack)" on Wikipedia (I'm sorry, I can't post more links due to reputation issues).

For the second case, your webserver might not be listening to your external IP address. You should let your webserver bind on `0.0.0.0` or `::` (the latter if you are using IPv6) which basically means 'bind on every address/network interface'.

If you are sure that the problem is not your webserver, you may need to [forward](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) port `80` which is used for web browsing.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question but there were some missing details.

Comment: I am using WAMP and yes, localhost is working, only the ddns address not. Where should I set the second case?

Comment: Check your `httpd.conf` (you should find it somewhere in the WAMP directory) and find the `Listen` directive. It should be like `Listen 80` or `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`, but **not** `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`. Also ensure that there isn't a `Deny from all` in the `<Directory /your/root>` directive. If everything is alright, this is probably a port forwarding problem. Follow the instructions I linked in the main answer for your router to open port 80. If you still have problems, post your `httpd.conf` and I'll look at it. Also I'm gonna give better replies when I get home (it's hard to write from mobile!)

Comment: I have set "Allow from all", but it is not working.
I have tried to test ports, but for 80: "application has that port locked"
Here is my httpd.conf file from C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf
http://pastebin.com/teSfmY0D
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I checked your file and it looks alright. I think it's definitely a port forwarding problem. First, assign a static IP to your PC (see [here](http://portforward.com/networking/staticip.htm)). Then, forward port 80 from your router to your IP address. You can find instructions [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/). You can use something like [this website](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) to check if the port has been opened successfully. (you may need to restart your router, and also some providers provide static and NATted IP addresses which do not allow forwarding).

Comment: Also you may need to allow Apache to receive external connections from Windows Firewall. Probably a popup dialog was shown when you first started Apache. If you clicked deny or ignored the request, you may need to fix it manually. [This](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) should help you too. (but first, forward the ports and see if it works).